# Windows batch autoanswer XCOPY /i

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have created a batch file which uses FOR command to read a file of FROM Directory, FROM File, TO Directory, TO File as the parameters. (I am giving the files NEW names in the destination)

Everything works great until I add a new file to the mix.

In `XCOPY /i` option says it is a directory (which is NOT true). IF I don't use `/i` it wants to know if it is a file or a directory. It is ALWAYS a File. Is there a way I can autoreply or does someone have another suggestions.

Comment: If you are copying single files then `copy` will also do what you need.

Comment: @foxidrive I use `xcopy` to copy individual files for the `/D` option, which `copy` does not support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo f|xcopy [options] [files*]
```

Answer (score 0):

A short investigation did not yield an easy command line parameter solution.

If I got you right, you are trying to copy a file from one directory to a new directory + give it a new name in the new directory. Copying to the new directory should work fine when you terminate target directory name with a tailing '\' (backslash) - this should result in a file with the same name in the target dir. Renaming this file to the new name will be straight forward. However, it's two commands instead of one...

In case this does not work for you: maybe you can illustrate your qn with a sample / snippet of the batch file?

Comment: Did you try what Endoro mentioned?

echo f | xcopy ...

... is where you put your xcopy command that you wanted to reply "f" to.

Putting "echo f |" at the start should pass "f" as the answer to xcopy command that you put at the end of the line.

Comment: Endoro answer is what I was looking for. Yours would also work if I had to go that way. I just did not know how to insert my answer. Thanks for your help. Ted